# Input addEventListener on change not firing

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, webpack, addeventlistener

I have a single input to upload a image.

**html**

```
<main>
    <input id="hs-p" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
</main>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let hsp = new HPS();
</script>
```

I want to listen for when this input changes ( when someones adds an image to it).

**js**

```
let imageInput = null;

class HSP {       
    constructor() {

        this.imageInput = document.getElementById('hs-p');

        if (this.imageInput) {
            this.imageInput.addEventListener("change", this.uploadImage());
        }
   }

    uploadImage() {
        console.log("upload image", this.imageInput);
    }
}

module.exports = HSP;
```

When someone adds an image it should call the uploadImage callaback. However this function is only firing once when the page loads and never fires when i add a image to the input or change the input image.

I am using node & webpack to output the above custom library/sdk which i then import into my html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your event to this:

```
this.imageInput.addEventListener("change", () => this.uploadImage());
```

Or to this:

```
this.imageInput.addEventListener("change", this.uploadImage.bind(this));
```

What you are doing is calling `uploadImage` and passing the result of that to the listener. You want to pass the reference to the listener.

Comment: Great, i cant believe i forgot about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change `this.imageInput.addEventListener("change", this.uploadImage());` to `this.imageInput.addEventListener("change", this.uploadImage);` ( removed the () after this.uploadImage ).