# Changing the element never triggers addEventListener

Tags: javascript

I am recieving measurements `_date` and `_time` from a device on regular intervals. When measurements arrive, I update the `innerHTML` of an element using:

```
document.getElementById("t_001").innerHTML = `${_date}, ${_time}`;
```

and element with ID `t_001` is changing it's value fine. Now I want to create a nice fade in fade out animation *(using opacity)* for the text whenever `inner.HTML` is updated.

---

In order to do this I want to manipulate CSS of the element through a function `animation()` like this:

```
let x = document.getElementById("t_001");

x.addEventListener("change", animation());

function animation(){
    // CSS Changes will take place here but this is never triggered...
    console.log(x);
}
```

But the function never triggers... How come?

Comment: There is no `change` event for `innerHTML`, only for `value` on form elements like `input`, `textarea`. What you need is a `MutationObserver`. Aside from that, your approach is more than questionable. Instead of the listener, make the code that changes the `innerHTML` apply a CSS class that results in the animation you need.

Comment: So what could I do here? I probably have to change the 1st chunk of code as well...

Comment: You can follow this article. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683026/input-addeventlistener-on-change-not-firing. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, `change` will not be triggered when the HTML of your element changes. But, seeing as the animation code needs to be in a different JS file and both files have access to the `t_001` element, you should be able to trigger a custom event from the first file when new data is received and detect it in the second.

#### File 1

```
let x = document.getElementById("t_001");
let e = new Event('customEvent');

x.innerHTML = `${_date}, ${_time}`;
x.dispatchEvent(e);
```

#### File 2

```
let x = document.getElementById("t_001");

x.addEventListener("customEvent", animation());

function animation() {
    console.log(x);
}
```